# Segmentation fault in parsing into linked list

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault

I have this program that parses and RSS feed into a linked list.

```
#include"util.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<string.h>

void parse_tc(){

    struct node *head = NULL;
    char *bytes = 0;

    struct stat st;
    stat("techcrunch.txt", &st);

    int size = st.st_size;
    FILE *f = fopen("techcrunch.txt", "rb");

    bytes = (char*)malloc(size + 1);
    size_t nread = fread(bytes,1,size,f);
    bytes[nread] = 0;
    fclose(f);


    struct node *temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->position = 1;
    printf("%d. ", temp->position);
    char *a = title_parser_tc(bytes,temp);
    head = temp;

    for(int i = 2; i<21; i++){
            temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->position = i;
            printf("%d. ", temp->position);
            a = title_parser_tc(a, temp);
            struct node* temp1 = head;

            while(temp1->link != NULL)
            {
                    temp1 = temp1->link;
            }
            temp1->link = temp;

    }

    free(bytes);
    int holder = 0;
    int check = 0;
    do {
            printf("Enter a number: ");
            scanf("%d", &holder);
            if(holder<1 || holder > 20){
                    puts("Invalid input");
                    check = 1;
            }
            else{
                    check = 0;
            }
    } while(check);

    get_feed(holder, head);
}

char* title_parser_tc(char *bytes, struct node *temp){


    char *ptr = strstr(bytes, "<title>");

    if (ptr) {

            ptr += 7;
            char *ptr2 = strstr(ptr, "</title>");

            if (ptr2) {

                    char* output = malloc(ptr2 - ptr + 1);
                    memcpy(output, ptr, ptr2 - ptr);
                    output[ptr2 - ptr] = 0;

                    if(strcmp(output,"TechCrunch")!=0){

                            temp->title = output;
                            puts(temp->title);
                            temp->link = NULL;free(output);

                            char *load = pubdate_parser_tc(ptr2, temp);
                            return load;
                    }
                    else{

                            char *load = title_parser_tc(ptr2, temp);
                            free(output);
                            return load;
                    }
            }
    }
    return NULL;
}

char* pubdate_parser_tc(char *bytes, struct node *temp){

    char *ptr = strstr(bytes, "<pubDate>");

    if (ptr) {

            ptr += 9;
            char *ptr2 = strstr(ptr, "</pubDate>");

            if (ptr2) {
                    char* output = malloc(ptr2 - ptr + 1);
                    memcpy(output, ptr, ptr2 - ptr);
                    output[ptr2 - ptr] = 0;
                    temp->pubdate = output;
                    free(output);
                    char *load = description_parser_tc(ptr2, temp);
                    return load;

            }
    }
    return NULL;
}

char* description_parser_tc(char *bytes, struct node *temp){

    char *ptr = strstr(bytes, "<description>");

    if (ptr) {

            ptr += 13;
            char *ptr2 = strstr(ptr, "</description>");
            if (ptr2){
                    char* output = malloc(ptr2 - ptr + 1);
                    memcpy(output, ptr, ptr2 - ptr);

                    output[ptr2 - ptr] = 0;
                    description_cleaner_tc(output, temp);
                    free(output);

                    char *load = url_parser_tc(ptr2, temp);
                    return load;
            }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void description_cleaner_tc(char *bytes, struct node *temp){

    char *ptr = strstr(bytes, "&amp;nbsp;");

    if (ptr) {

            ptr += 10;
            char *ptr2 = strstr(ptr, "&lt;a ");
            if (ptr2) {
                    char* output = malloc(ptr2 - ptr + 1);
                    memcpy(output, ptr, ptr2 - ptr);
                    output[ptr2 - ptr] = 0;
                    temp->description = output;
                    puts(temp->description);
                    free(output);
            }
    }
}

char* url_parser_tc(char *bytes, struct node *temp){
    char *ptr = strstr(bytes, "href");

    if (ptr) {

            ptr += 6;
            char *ptr2 = strstr(ptr, "&gt;");

            if (ptr2) {
                    char* output = (char*)malloc(ptr2 - ptr);
                    memcpy(output, ptr, ptr2 - ptr - 1);
                    output[ptr2 - ptr - 1] = 0;
                    temp->url = output;
                    puts(temp->pubdate);
                    puts(temp->url);
                    puts("");
                    free(output);
                    return ptr2;
            }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

My problem is that for this file `textcrunch.txt`, my program occurs a segmentation fault at around the 10th loop in `parse_tc()`. The program works for another file but this file gives me an error. Any solution?

The code is basically the same function repeated for different strings to be parsed.

Comment: Hmmm `char *ptr = strstr(bytes, "href"); ... ptr += 6;`.  Why 6?

Comment: If `The program works for another file but this file gives me an error` then you need to provide the content of a file that works and the one that doesn't so we can try it ourselves.  Otherwise we might pick a file that works.

Comment: `for(int i = 2; i<21; i++)`  `ptr += 7;` `ptr += 9;` seem to be magic numbers: are they correct for all cases???

Comment: What happens if your program is fed malformed HTML or tags that span mutliple lines?  I'd also make your tags constants and strlen() them to get rid of the magic numbers.

Comment: This code produces _dozens_ of compiler warning or error messages. The majority of which are independent of the fact I have no idea what is contained in your `util.h` header file. So first off, read your compiler's output, and use it as your guide. This question, as it is, could be subjected to being closed, as it presently stands, as it is only about debugging your program, not about a developing useful question and answer that is useful to the entire community. Your code should be rewritten to become a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault usually means dereferencing a null-pointer (or a pointer to uninitialized memory). If you are using GCC or Clang, you can recompile with the `-g` flag and run the resulting program through `gdb`:

```
gdb --args ....
r
bt
```

The first line starts gdb, supply your command as you would usually run it. `r` starts the run and `bt` gives a backtrace from the point your program stops with the segmentation fault. At least this gives you the location in the code the problem occurs. You could start futher debugging with print statements or add some defensive coding there.